# Confusion on the cost function in video lecture

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am unable to understand the graph of 2nd and 3rd in the below.

1. What does "x" represent here? In graph 1 the value of x doesn't matter as theta 1 is zero. But in graph 2 and 3 which is the value of "x"?
2. In graph 2, how did the instructor decide that h(x) value is 2?

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are confused about.  In the graph, x is the horizontal axis, while h{theta}(x) is the vertical axis.  I'm not sure what else can be inferred from just that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` can be *any* independent variable. A signal from a sensor, a person's age, my weight after an all you can eat buffet, ...

theta0 is the zeroth order, i.e. independent of `x`.
theta1 is the first order, linear with `x`.

In graph 2:  theta0 is 0, theta1 is 0.5.  Thus when `x` is 2.  `h = 0 + 0.5*2 = 1`